# How do I convert Latin1 into UTF-8 in XML correctly?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I am using an XML request to send SMS. It has UTF-8 encoding, but my string is in Norwegian.

Here part of my string:

```
Trykk på linken for å få
```

In SMS I get this:

```
"Trykk pÃ¥ linken for Ã¥ fÃ¥"
```

But this string is incorrect.

I tried to use "[Solving Latin1 and UTF8 errors for good in Ruby](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/12/07/solving-latin1-and-utf8-errors-for-good-in-ruby.html)", but the problems stayed.

I am using an XML request to send SMS. It uses UTF-8 encoding, but my string is in Norwegian.

Here's part of my string:

```
Trykk på linken for å få
```

In SMS I get this:

```
"Trykk pÃ¥ linken for Ã¥ fÃ¥"
```

but this string is incorrect.

I tried to use "[Solving Latin1 and UTF8 errors for good in Ruby](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/12/07/solving-latin1-and-utf8-errors-for-good-in-ruby.html)", but the problems stayed.

Comment: I don't understand. Your `a` string is already UTF-8 so why the `force_encoding('iso-8859-1')` call?

Comment: @mu is too short, I meant, that I THINK, that Ruby is doing this. I will edit post.

Comment: So you're getting `"Trykk pÃ¥ linken for Ã¥ fÃ¥"`, it claims to be UTF-8, and it looks like something is doing a `force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')` to get from `'Trykk på linken for å få'` to get the final mess of nonsense? You're building the XML using `'Trykk på linken for å få'` and `"Trykk pÃ¥ linken for Ã¥ fÃ¥"` comes out the other side, correct? How does the XML get built and what encoding to the strings think they have at the beginning?

Comment: @muistooshort, I build it using gem. Here is link to file, where header is set - https://github.com/PSWinCom/pswincomgem/blob/master/lib/pswincom/httpsender.rb.. Here is link to class, which is building XML - https://github.com/PSWinCom/pswincomgem/blob/master/lib/pswincom/request.rb.

Comment: when I run `warn text.encoding.inspect` it gives me `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`

Comment: PSWinCom service has admin page. When I looked there, I saw, that `Message Type Alphanumeric text`

Comment: I think you might have to open an issue at github or try debugging the gem yourself to see where it is screwing up the encoding.

Comment: @muistooshort, gem wasn't supported for 2 years.

Comment: @muistooshort, I found, that in Phyton was similar situation - https://github.com/PSWinCom/pswinpy/pull/2